Icons not being rendered properly in Windows Emacs installation
I have installed GNU Emacs 29.3 recently and I'm trying to setup a custom config. But I have been noticing that some of the icons are not being rendered properly in the Emacs UI.
Below is a screenshot of the mode-line in various buffers


I'm not sure why this is happening

Does this answer your question? Strange symbols in doom-modeline

Thank you for sharing this, although the solution is the same, I was facing the problem even without installing doom-modeline. But the same solution seems to have worked

After doing a lot of research, I found a similar question posted in doom-modeline GitHub repo - which mentions that you need to install nerd-icons using the command M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts.

Also note that I have doom-modeline package installed (M-x package-install RET doom-modeline, but I was facing this issue even before installing the doom-modeline package

M-x nerd-icons-install-fonts downloads the font files with the extension .ttf in the location specified by you. You then need to manually install the fonts by double clicking on the file and clicking install.
And this finally solved my problem. Below are the screenshots of final result


